# Does there exist an analytic function $f$ on $D(0,1)$ such that $f(z_n)=0$ for even $n$ and $f(z_n)=1$ for odd $n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Given that $(z_n)$ is a sequence of distinct points in $D(0,1)=\{z \in \Bbb C : |z| \lt 1\}$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n=0$, Can we find an analytic function $f$ such that

$f(z_n)= \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if n is even} \\ 1, & \text{if n is odd} \end{cases}$
?

I know the Uniqueness theorem and Identity theorem. How can I use them?

Also as $n \to \infty$, we have $f(z_n)$ to be divergent. Is this information of any help?

Comment: Here is a related example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614673/is-there-an-holomorphic-function-if-that-function-exists-is-it-unique/1615047#1615047

Comment: Every analytic function is continuous

Comment: @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura note that 0 does not lie in the domain.

Comment: @s.harp: How does $0$ not lie in the domain $\{z \in \Bbb C : |z| \lt 1\}$?

Comment: @MartinR it appears I have misunderstood the domain to be $(0,1)$

Comment: @s.harp I have wrote down the domain already. :)

Comment: @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura Perhaps this is an ultimate hint!! great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said in the comments, every analytic function is in 
particular continuous (since differentiability in a point implies
continuity in that point).

If an analytic function $f$ would exist with the given properties, then
both
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} z_{2n} = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad f(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(z_{2n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0
$$
and
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} z_{2n+1} = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad f(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(z_{2n+1}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 = 1
$$
which is apparently not possible.

Comment: ...this is simply superb.....i want your brain sir...

Answer (score 3):

The zeros of a nonzero analytic function are isolated and so there exists no function satisfying your hypotheses.